# VBA Excel, Selenium - Loop through radio button values to find the selected value and print it

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to know which radio button option is selected.  I am looking for a way to loop through the radio button responses and print the one with checked = 'Checked'.  Everything I have tried returns all of the options or returns nothing.

here is a snippet of the html

```html
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#f46f66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d3e2e5';" style="background-color: rgb(155, 300, 59);">
   <td width="80%">Select a fruit</td><td width="20%">  
      <input type="radio" name="FruitOptions" value="Peach" checked="checked" disabled="disabled">Peach<br>         
      <input type="radio" name="FruitOptions" value="Apple" disabled="disabled">Apple<br></td></tr>
      <input type="radio" name="FruitOptions" value="Orange" disabled="disabled">Orange<br></td></tr>
```

I am using vba selenium to scrape a website for this information.

Here is what I have tried

```
enter code here
           Chrome.Wait 100
                    
            Set seconds = Chrome.FindElementsByTag("tr")

            j = 2
            s = 2
            
            Set mysheet = Sheets("Sheet7")
            

                For Each second In seconds

                On Error Resume Next
                
                mysheet.Cells(j, s).Value = second.FindElementsByTag("td")(2).Text
                
    
                    Set inputvs = second.FindElementsByTag("input")
                    
                         For Each inputv In inputvs
        
                            If inputv.Attribute("checked").Value = "checked" Then

             'This is where my issue is 
             'I want to print the value with the checked attribute            

                                Debug.Print (inputv.Attribute("value"))
                                
                                mysheet.Cells(j, s).Value = inputv.getAttribute("value")
                                
                              
                            Else
                            
                                Debug.Print ("none")
                                
                            End If
                         
                         Next
                        


                j = j + 1

                
                Next
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide your attempts so that we can help you. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, how is the selenium tag relevant?

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) css selectors and no need for a loop. You specify the css pattern for the `checked` attribute with value = `checked`, that occurs in an element which also has a `name` attribute with value `FruitOptions`.

```
Debug.Print chrome.FindElementByCss("[name=FruitOptions][checked=checked]").Attribute("value")
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to add what I came up with to help anyone else that find themselves in a similar situation.  The answer QHarr provided would have been great if there was one set of radio buttons I was looping through but the form I am getting this information from has a few.

This is what I ended up doing.

```
Chrome.Wait 100
            Set seconds = Chrome.FindElementsByTag("tr")
            
            j = 2
            s = 2
            
            Set mysheet = Sheets("Sheet7")

                For Each second In seconds

                On Error Resume Next
                
                mysheet.Cells(j, s).Value = second.FindElementsByTag("td")(2).Text
                
                
                    Set inputvs = second.FindElementsByTag("input")
                    
                         For Each inputv In inputvs

                            If inputv.Attribute("checked") = True Then

                                mysheet.Cells(j, s).Value = (inputv.Attribute("value"))

                            Else
                            
                                
                            End If
                         
                         Next
                        


                j = j + 1

                
                Next
```